# Vim function toggle replace character under cursor

Tags: vim

I'm trying to change "X" to " " and vice versa to mark a checkbox in a markdown file in normal mode:

```
- [X] Zucchini
- [ ] Nutmeg
```

Here's what I've tried:

First

```
function! ToggleComplete()
  if getline('.')[col('.')-1] == 'X'
    return ' '
  else
    return 'X'
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-x> :call ToggleComplete()<CR>
```

Second

```
function! ToggleComplete()
  if getline('.')[col('.')-1] == 'X'
    return '\r\<Space>'
  else
    return '\rX'
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-x> :call ToggleComplete()<CR>
```

Comment: Why not simply `rX` and `r<space>`?

Comment: Is it for vimwiki plugin? If so, `nmap <C-x> <Plug>VimwikiToggleListItem` should do it.

Comment: and what did not work? I am missing the problem here.

Comment: `return` does not change text, it only "returns" a value. Maybe you need to use `setline` or some other more convenient functions which I don't know.

Comment: @romainl I need it bound conditionally to a single binding

Comment: @Amadan No, just for Github TODOs mainly

Comment: No. You *want* it bound conditionally to a single binding. Big difference.

Comment: @romainl Feel free to post a solution/help in any way

Comment: I already did. You are looking for a solution to a non-existent problem.

Comment: @romainl : why do u say it's not a problem? imho it seems useful to be able to toggle a checkbox with a single keystroke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really can't work like this; the main reason is how you use the `return` statement : your function returns a space or an X char, but the returned value is never used, and is lost when you use `call ToggleComplete()`. Actually there's nothing in your code that **changes** the content of your buffer.

A secondary point: your `if` test is very restrictive; it requires your cursor to be exactly on the right char in the line, in order to work (because of `[col('.')-1]`). Maybe it's what you want, but you may also add some flexibility by using a test which works without depending on the cursor column.

The following is one possibility of doing what you want:

```
function! ToggleComplete()
    " Get current line:
    let l:line = getline('.')

    " Get the char to test with the help of a pattern, ' ' or 'X':
    " \zs and \ze lets you retrieve only the part between themselves:
    let l:char = matchstr(l:line, '\[\zs.\ze]')

    " Invert the value:
    if l:char == 'X'
        let l:char = ' '
    else
        let l:char = 'X'
    endif

    " Replace the current line with a new one, with the right
    " char substituted:
    call setline(line('.'), substitute(l:line, '\[\zs.\ze]', l:char, ''))

    " Please note that this last line is doing the desired job. There is
    " no need to return anything
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks yolenoyer. Yeah, it seemed that return wouldn't do anything unless you were in insert mode, so thanks for clarifying that, I don't know Vimscript at all. I appreciate the commented code, but now there's a new problem: I can toggle the " " to X, but cannot back from X to " ".

Comment: Is your "X" char really uppercase?

Comment: Yes, it changes from `[ ]` to `[X]`, but not `[X]` to `[ ]`. Thanks for shining some light on not having to be on the exact column, this is great.

Comment: After doing some debugging, I've found that the `matchstr()` always results in an empty value (never `X`).

Comment: @djv : so please try to correct the pattern I gave (`^-\s*\[\zs.\ze]`) for your own use; maybe there are some spaces missing (maybe try `^\s*-\s*\[\zs.\ze]`), maybe there's something else : then try to search directly the given pattern (for debug) with `/` : `/^-\s*\[\zs.\ze]`; see `:h pattern` for help about patterns.

Comment: I played around with it earlier for about an hour with no success.

Comment: @djv : "with no success" --> so why did you check my answer??

Comment: Well if it's working for you, it must be an error on my side, right? I feel you've done enough for free to warrant the check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103346/discussion-between-yolenoyer-and-djv).